# What causes unique key prop warning in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I keep getting this warning when testing a react-admin app:

```
    Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

    Check the top-level render call using <SimpleForm>. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.

      at NumberInput (node_modules/ra-ui-materialui/src/input/NumberInput.tsx:23:14)
      at CoreAdminRoutes (node_modules/ra-core/src/core/CoreAdminRoutes.tsx:18:42)
      at RenderedRoute (node_modules/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx:624:26)
      at Routes (node_modules/react-router/lib/components.tsx:410:3)
      at CoreAdminUI (node_modules/ra-core/src/core/CoreAdminUI.tsx:54:14)
          at div
      at node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-b63ca7c6.cjs.dev.js:43:23
      at ScopedCssBaseline (node_modules/@mui/material/node/ScopedCssBaseline/ScopedCssBaseline.js:58:44)
      at AdminUI (node_modules/ra-ui-materialui/src/AdminUI.tsx:14:39)
      at ThemeProvider (node_modules/@mui/private-theming/node/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js:39:5)
      at ThemeProvider (node_modules/@mui/system/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js:49:5)
      at ThemeProvider (node_modules/@mui/material/node/styles/ThemeProvider.js:20:14)
      at ThemeProvider (node_modules/ra-ui-materialui/src/layout/Theme/ThemeProvider.tsx:19:13)
      at ResourceDefinitionContextProvider (node_modules/ra-core/src/core/ResourceDefinitionContext.tsx:46:5)
      at NotificationContextProvider (node_modules/ra-core/src/notification/NotificationContextProvider.tsx:8:55)
      at I18nContextProvider (node_modules/ra-core/src/i18n/I18nContextProvider.tsx:13:5)
      at Router (node_modules/react-router/lib/components.tsx:328:13)
      at HistoryRouter (node_modules/ra-core/src/routing/HistoryRouter.tsx:11:13)
      at InternalRouter (node_modules/ra-core/src/routing/AdminRouter.tsx:39:13)
      at BasenameContextProvider (node_modules/ra-core/src/routing/BasenameContextProvider.tsx:12:51)
      at AdminRouter (node_modules/ra-core/src/routing/AdminRouter.tsx:14:12)
      at QueryClientProvider (node_modules/react-query/lib/react/QueryClientProvider.js:45:21)
      at PreferencesEditorContextProvider (node_modules/ra-core/src/preferences/PreferencesEditorContextProvider.tsx:8:60)
      at StoreContextProvider (node_modules/ra-core/src/store/StoreContextProvider.tsx:7:17)
      at CoreAdminContext (node_modules/ra-core/src/core/CoreAdminContext.tsx:54:14)
      at AdminContext (node_modules/ra-ui-materialui/src/AdminContext.tsx:8:62)
      at Admin (node_modules/react-admin/src/Admin.tsx:115:14)
      at App (src/App.js:480:18)
```

It occurs in this code:

```
    <Create redirect="show">
        <SimpleForm sanitizeEmptyValues warnWhenUnsavedChanges>
            {createInputs(resource, name, "add", permissions)}
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
```

`createInputs()` returns an array created like:

```
            components.push(<C {...props} />);
```

`C` is `NumberInput`, `TextInput` or similar.

When I console log, it shows that key=null. Yet, if I tweak it to `<C key={null} {...props} />`, then the warning disappears.

What is happening here and is there a better approach to fix it? I don't see anything in the react-admin documentation about a key prop, so I'm not sure why I'd need to specify it.

Comment: Yeah, but: don't use `key={null}`. The whole point of `key` attributes is so that React knows which virtual DOM element maps to which real DOM element. If you give everything the same key, all you've done is make it impossible for React to efficiently update the page. Use real keys, that identify "the thing itself" (so not an array index, but some property, or combination of properties, that uniquely identifies "that thing" so React can do its job). React will run in  reduced performance by using array position if you omit or explicitly set it to something nullish.

Comment: Right, but the question is why do I need to do this in react-admin, and seemingly only in this part of the code? Other parts like the list view don't seem to trigger such an error. There are no examples I've seen in the react-admin documentation that include a key. I'm pretty sure they'd include it somewhere if it was expected for you to include it yourself and not already handled by react-admin.

Comment: It's universal React, one of the core things you learn about React, when you learn React =) It wouldn't make a lot of sense for individual libraries to have to remind you of that (in the same way they don't have to remind you how to call a function in JS. You already know how to do that). Any time you create an array of React components, each of those components should have a `key` attribute so that React doesn't rewrite the entire associated DOM tree just because one of them moved up or down a spot in the array.

Comment: Is there a difference between an array and hardcoding the elements between the start and end tag? If not, then I still don't understand why it wouldn't be in the react-admin tutorials, e.g. there's no key attribute used in this demo (and I'm sure it doesn't trigger the warning): https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html#adding-creation-capabilities

Comment: Yes, there is, a _huge_ difference: JSX is not JS, it needs to get transpiled to real JS before it can get run, and that transpilation process includes adding keys as part of the conversion. Something that you have to do yourself when you're "already using JS" by putting components in arrays (either manually or by using array.map etc). [Which is why React tells you about that](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key).

Comment: Yep, OK, makes a lot more sense now. Using arrays is unconventional for react-admin, which explains why there is nothing in their documentation that shows using key. I'm assuming that for react-admin, a good solution will be to use `source` (i.e. `key={props['source']}` or similar). If you'd like to write that information up as an answer, then I can accept it.

Comment: This is, again, React basics, so instead I'll just vote to close it as a duplicate of one of the many "why am I getting `key` related errors" questions.

Answer (score 0):

React processes every node of the DOM using this unique key, if you are mapping an array then give unique value to the `key` attribute of the outer JSX tag: `[].map(item,i)=><p key={"myKey-"+i}></p>`

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

When using an imported component you are effectively creating a new instance of that component which can be done multiple times. React DOM notices this and to preemptively avoid issues it will warn to add a key to help the DOM differentiate each child or instance created.

### Explanation

Without a key, the parent component could create 1-1000+ instances such as a mapping. If there is no unique key then the DOM will possibly have issues during re-renders, updates, state changes and ref logic.

You can avoid this by adding a key='uniqueIdentifier' for any HTML elements within children that are iterated over or instantiated.

### Example ## ( with no errors )

```
export const MapExample = () => {
  const DummyList = [
    { name: "KYle", message: "hi", key: "uniqueKey1" },
    { name: "Jeff", message: "bye", key: "uniqueKey2" },
    { name: "Jason", message: "no", key: "uniqueKey3" },
    { name: "Bill", message: "yes", key: "uniqueKey4" },
    { name: "Remy", message: "maybe", key: "uniqueKey5" },
  ];

  return DummyList.map((listItem) => {
    return (
      <div key={listItem.key}>
        Name:{listItem.name}
        Message:{listItem.message}
      </div>
    );
  });
};
```

Essentially when instantiating elements **we need to add a key to the wrapping element** so react DOM can track and clean it up correctly.

Let me know if that helps or if something is still confusing/not working. (if so please provide the code or the return statement of your component creator or where your map method is)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).